# Accessing old version of referenced table in trigger function - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, trigger

In my database I have a table named "layer" and a table named "grouplayer". The table "layer" is referencing the table "grouplayer" by a foreign key constraint with Cascade DELETE.
I have added a trigger function to the table "layer" which is getting the value of another column of the table "grouplayer" by a SELECT query.  The function is working as intended when I delete a row of the table "layer". However if I delete a row of the table "grouplayer", the function doesn't work as the result of the SELECT query is NULL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE 
    pro TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT project into pro from grouplayer WHERE id = old.grouplayer_id;
    -- Query = NULL. How can I access project from grouplayer before deleting?

    RETURN NEW;
END
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I can't access the grouplayer even though I have included the keyword Before in the Create Trigger Statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER some_trig BEFORE DELETE ON layer FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE some_func ()
```

Comment: Hi welcome to the forum, please take a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @McNets That link was useful, and is a must-read. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look at the code, but obviously the row is deleted from `grouplayer` *before* the `BEFORE` trigger on `layer` is executed.

Perhaps you can perform the task in a `BEFORE` trigger on `layer`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I can’t test this myself with your data, but you might try the following:

- Make this a `BEFORE` trigger, which you have already.
- In your TRIGGER function `RETURN OLD` (*not* `NEW`).

This certainly worked for one of my triggers.

You can see a working example on [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=90254674fd161fe008f3bbd8da005a0f)